# How to import certificates in Cisco AnyConnect iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, vpn

In order to connect to a private network the connection should have IKE RSA - IPSEC. The default VPN connection settings that is in the settings of iPhone does not have this. The Cisco AnyConnect app have this option but the digital certificates that are visible in the default VPN are not visible in the AnyConnect app. Also the certificate import in the AnyConnect app asks for a URL instead of opening the file browser.

How to install a certificate so that it is detected by the AnyConnect app

**Edit:** After a lot of digging I found out that the certificates detected by Cisco AnyConnect should be in SSL template and not in other template. So, how do I convert a p12 certificate that I have into a SSL templated certificate.

Comment: You should install [Cisco Legacy AnyConnect](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cisco-legacy-anyconnect/id392790924?mt=8).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to would be to email the certificates to your iphone and install from there.

```
1. Tap attached certificate in the email sent to your iphone
2. Tap install
```

Next, you'll associate the certificate in Cisco AnyConnect:

```
3. Choose desired conection > then select detail disclosure button
4. Tap Advanced > Certificate
5. Tap the name of the certificate you just imported
```

Comment: I've done the above but the certificate is not showing in the Advanced > Certificate section . I've imported a p12 certificate . But the same certificate is visible in the default VPN setup that comes with the phone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation for Cisco Any Connection Application on iOS. Certain certificate will not be visible. However if the certificate has Digital Signature KU, it should show up.

```
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Key Usage: critical
          Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
```

You can check the following command to dump the certificate:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in my_cert.pem
```